# React-hook-form Errors disappear after Redux state change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hook-form

The form's errors disappear when values changed by redux hook.

See the full example at sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-banach-d4hhk6?file=/src/App.js
CAUTION!
Uncommenting the useEffect calling trigger can potentially cause an infinite loop, resulting in high CPU usage and potential RAM overflow.

And short explanation:

```js
/**
 * PROBLEM WITH DISAPPEARING ERRORS
 * Inputs dispatching changes to redux store
 * Then redux useSelector returns new values and causes render
 * The form have the changed values
 * But the errors are lost
 * See console.group() below
 */

const joiSchema = Joi.object({
  quantity: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(10).required(),
  price: Joi.number().integer().min(1).max(999).required(),
});

const MyItem = ({ itemId }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { quantity, price } = useSelector((state) =>
    selectItemById(state, itemId)
  );

  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    getValues,
  } = useForm({
    mode: "all",
    resolver: joiResolver(joiSchema),
    values: { quantity, price },
  });

  const change = (changes) => {
    dispatch(
      itemUpdated({
        id: itemId,
        changes,
      })
    );
  };

  console.group("Render");
  console.log("getValues()", getValues()); // correct after change
  console.log("errors", errors); // ! always empty after change
  console.groupEnd();

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        style={{ color: Boolean(errors.quantity) ? "red" : "black" }}
        {...register("quantity", {
          onChange: (event) => change({ quantity: Number(event.target.value) }),
        })}
      />
      <input
        type="text"
        style={{ color: Boolean(errors.price) ? "red" : "black" }}
        {...register("price", {
          onChange: (event) => change({ price: Number(event.target.value) }),
        })}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

We need the form to be synchronized between tabs.
The form fields changes should be saved before submit.
Currently we solve it with trigger in useEffect, but we think there is a better proper solution.
For some reason this solution not working in provided full example.

We tried all the options from docs, including `Controller`, `defaultValues`, `resetOptions`, etc.

We also posted this question in project's (react-hook-form) discord channel.

The problem looks like linked to the validation trigger mechanism that don't work when values changed by redux useSelector hook

Please see the full example in sandbox.